# Client Side logging in Applet

Tags: java, logging, applet

I have an applet which runs on the client machine. I want to obtain logs or store logs on client side. I know Java console shows all the errors/exceptions.

Any way I can store those logs in a file?

Answer (score 1):

> Any way I can store those logs in a file?

Sure.  So long as the applet is trusted, it should be able to write files under (at least) the `user.home` path.  A trusted app. can also redirect `System.out` and `System.err` streams to wherever they are needed.

But then, why is the logging API dumping info. to the console or standard out?  Surely it has a facility to put the output wherever and however the user (the programmer) wants.